# Post a status update to twitter using c#

Tags: c#, twitter

Every Example I can find is either very outdated or always comes back 401.
Can anyone at all provide a working example of posting a status update to twitter?

Even the below always fails. 
I get redirected to twitter - great. I can confrim the access codes are correct and match my application, but on acutally posting the update - error is unknown...

What on earth is wrong here? Does matter what app I use or which twitter account.

Using Twitteriser2.dll

```
if (Request["oauth_token"] == null)
        {
            OAuthTokenResponse reqToken = OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken(
                oauth_consumer_key,
                oauth_consumer_secret,
                Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);

            Response.Redirect(string.Format("http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token={0}",
                reqToken.Token));
        }
        else
        {
            string requestToken = Request["oauth_token"].ToString();
            string pin = Request["oauth_verifier"].ToString();

            var tokens = OAuthUtility.GetAccessToken(
                oauth_consumer_key,
                oauth_consumer_secret,
                requestToken,
                pin);

            OAuthTokens accesstoken = new OAuthTokens()
            {
                AccessToken = tokens.Token,
                AccessTokenSecret = tokens.TokenSecret,
                ConsumerKey = oauth_consumer_key,
                ConsumerSecret = oauth_consumer_secret
            };

            TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> response = TwitterStatus.Update(
                accesstoken,
                "Testing!! It works (hopefully).");

            if (response.Result == RequestResult.Success)
            {
                Response.Write("we did it!");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("it's all bad.");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately you're probably going to have a hard time getting this answered. To be honest social networks hate this type of automation, Pinterest is nearly impossible to sign in and POST.  You may want to look for a better solution such as Selenium or PhantomJS.

Comment: Twitter provides an API and documentation for exactly this sort of thing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got it working eventually.
The fault isn't exactly known as I didn't have to change the code but what I did was re-download Twitterizwer and Built it (Required adding a ref to C++ components for what ever reason) and it then worked so I can only see that it was somehow faulty the first time round.

Answer (score 0):

The TwitterRepsonse object has an "ErrorMessage" property.  You should probably start by looking at the information in there to give you some guidance.

Comment: In that case, then you're going to have to find a way to intercept the response that is coming back from Twitter.  I have two suggestions.  First: Download the Twitterizer source code and compile it into your application, then step through the Twitterizer source until you find the place where the response is received and see what Twitter is actually saying. This is probably your best bet.  Another option would be to use a tool like Fiddler to capture the http response and look at it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Tweetinvi. Tweetinvi will allow you to post in 1 line and get error messages in line too. Here is an example.

```
TwitterCredentials.SetCredentials("Access_Token", "Access_Token_Secret", "Consumer_Key", "Consumer_Secret");
var tweet = Tweet.PublishTweet("Hello!");

if (tweet == null)
{
    var exceptionDetails = ExceptionHandler.GetLastException().TwitterExceptionInfos.First().Message;
}
```

You can find the documentation here : https://tweetinvi.codeplex.com/documentation

Also have a look at https://tweetinvi.codeplex.com/discussions/536895 if you are using it with ASP.NET.